# OSX and iOs Bluetooth LE Connection

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to set up a Bluetooth LE Connection between my iPhone (CBPeripheralManager) and my Macbook Pro (CBCentralManager)

I can discover my iPhone, I can read the RSSI value and I get the advertisement packet with my service uuid. **But the uuid is reversed!**

If I call connectPeripheral nothing happens - no callback or anything, but when looking at the Bluetooth-Icon in the status-bar I can see my iPhone connected as the Custom-Service - so why don't I get the **didConnectPeripheral**-Callback ?!

I hope somebody has an idea what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the retain my CBPeripheral - because I'm using ARC, I have to obviously add it to a NSMutableArray!

- The reversed UUID is still up for discussion!